# Unique coroutine Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I need help to find out if I can do the following.

The saveAnswer method can be slow, but I want to enqueue the calls to the saveAnswer method, so as not to have several parallel threads, but a single process (coroutine) that executes executeProcess

So if the saveAnswer method is called very fast, you will not have concurrency problems due to having many threads.

[image: example]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does `executeProcess` depend in any way on `answer`?

Comment: (I can see two plausible solutions.  One is to just launch `jobTest` eagerly, at setup, and have it wait on e.g. a `CompletableJob` or `CompletableDeferred`.  Another is to have an `AtomicBoolean` CAS to determine the first call and let it and only it launch the coroutine.)